# As a player, how can I deal with a fundamentally annoying teammate

Tags: dnd-5e, problem-players, roleplaying, group-dynamics

I play in my school's D&D club and our first year was last year.  During that first year, one of my fellow players rolled a sorcerer with high charisma (17) but low intelligence (8).  He roleplayed his character however as if his intelligence is a 2 or 3, where his character knew nothing, messed up plans on purpose, and frequently injured his teammates with AOE spells.

When that school year ended, I thought I was rid of this character. But when the club reformed, he used the exact same character again and has gone even further to be annoying and mess people up.

How can I get him to contribute to the team or get him to stop acting obnoxious?

Comment: how many people are in your party, and are they as annoyed by this behavior as you are?  Does your club have a faculty advisor?

Comment: Related: [What is “my guy syndrome” and how do I handle it?](/questions/37103), [How to deal with a disruptive player?](/questions/61884)

Comment: *"He roleplayed his character however as if his intelligence is a 2 or 3, where his character knew nothing, messed up plans on purpose, and frequently injured his teammates with AOE spells"* — what is the rationale behind this behavior? Does the player enjoy injuring teammates, or does he think it is an appropriate (or maybe the only one) way to roleplay? Did you ask him about this?

Comment: Somewhat related: [How can I play dumb?](/questions/11856)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yikes...**

I see where this would be irritating. I would have a heart to heart with this player. If he's new, explain to him an 8 may have a -1 mod to it, but is really just a slightly lower average intelligence. Like a C to D student. Explain to him that it's more fun as a group if he contributes and how it can be upsetting to other PCs when he does what he does.

If it continues I would have your DM/GM give him the same talk. If it is a problem from there I would consider talking to your group and club advisor. Maybe he is new and just wants attention or someone to guide him. Be kind, but firm. He shouldn't get to ruin your fun, but try to understand why he does what he does.

Comment: If you're going down the route of speaking with the DM, you might want to refer them to this popular internet opinion of DnD stat/real world correlation as a reasonable guideline: https://homebrewery.naturalcrit.com/print/Ek0DG9aax

Comment: FWIW that chart is shamelessly stolen from a [DMing with Charisma blogpost](https://dmingwithcharisma.com/2011/10/dd-stats-in-simple-language/#comment-47686) which has been revised since the copy-pasta.

Answer (score 1):

### Talk to the player about [my guy syndrome](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37103/what-is-my-guy-syndrome-and-how-do-i-handle-it)

The numbers on your character sheet are not a licence to be a d%^&.